# Time validation in C

Tags: c, validation

I am doing a simple Time validation, which is it would accept a start time and a end time.

both time would be in 24 hours system format.

The time only can be exactly hours like : "0800, 0900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400..."

which mean cant be like : "0830,0920,1025,1112,...

Could anyone please suggest me which most efficient technique I can use to complete this task of **validate the user input start time and end time.**

My Code

```
int validate_time();

int main();

char start_time[5] ="0800", "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300", "1400", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800", "1900", "2000";
char end_time[5] ="0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300", "1400", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800", "1900", "2000", "2100:;

int start_time;
int end_time;

main() {
    int start_time()
    int end_time()
} 

int validate_time() {
    switch ( validate_time ) {

    //if the input match with the function call
    case 1:
         int start_time();
         return 1;
         break;

    case 2:
         int end_time();
         return 1;
         break;

    default:
         printf("Time crash, please try again: \n");
         return 0;             
             main();
     }
}
```

Comment: Is it a code or pseudocode?

Comment: Does the start and end times are always for the same day?

Comment: I was curious about that as well... I mean, suppose this was an event planner and there was a New Year's Eve party. The party might start around 2100 and end sometime around 0300 the next day.

Answer (score 3):

Since the input is a 4 character string, you can check each digit separately:

**Most important** check: At the start, check if each character is a digit or not
then check these conditions,

1) Digit 1 should be `<= 2`
2) When Digit 1 is `2`, Digit 2 should be `<= 3`
3) Digit 3 should be `<= 5`  (Of course, in this case this check may not be required)

**UPDATE:**
Method 2:

1) You can take time input in **integer format** instead of string.
2) Now since you have only 24 combinations possible for time values, save them in array, i.e. **make a look-up table**.
3) Now since you have saved the time values in ascending order in the array, you can just **implement binary search** for the time entered by user.

**UPDATE 2:**
Example for Method 2:

You have an integer array containing all possible time values:

```
int possible_times = {0, 100, 200, 300, ..., 2300}; 
// Note that you cannot place '0' before every number, otherwise compiler will 
// treat them as octal values
```

Now you get user input:

```
scanf("%u", &time_in);
```

To validate the input time `time_in`, you can search the `possible_times` array. One way to do that is `Linear Search Algorithm`, comparing each element in array with `time_in`. Another way is using `Binary Search`, since your array is sorted.

Using Binary Search you will have to perform at most `5` comparisons, while with linear search, you may have to do upto `24` comparisons, that's why I suggested binary search.

P.S. : If you do not know about binary search, then read about it.

Comment: For method 2 I could understand the first and second, but I have no idea what is binary search for the time entered by user. Would you mind to explain to me what is it? How to do it?

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation with example. I got it done using an integer array and linear search.

Answer (score 1):

You specified time should be a whole hour - this seems to imply that you want to check that the input is

1. three or four digits
2. last two digits are zero

This would look something like this (assuming the input was a C string):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int testTime(char *inputString) {
  int ii, l, t_hrs = 0;
  l = strlen(inputString);
  if (l > 4) {
    printf("string '%s' is too long!\n", inputString);
    return -1;
  }
  for(ii = 0; ii < l; ii++) {
    if(!isdigit(inputString[ii])) {
      printf("input contains something other than digits!\n");
      return -1;
    }
    if(ii > 1 && inputString[ii] != '0') {
      printf("only whole hours can be entered!\n");
      return -1;
    }
    if(ii < 2) {
      t_hrs = 10* t_hrs + inputString[ii] - '0';
    }
  }
  if(t_hrs > 23) {
    printf("time is greater than 23 hours\n");
    return -1;
  }
  return t_hrs;
}

int main(void) {
  char t[] = "1130";
  printf("the time is %d\n", testTime("1200"));
  printf("the time is %d\n", testTime("1200am"));
  printf("the time is %d\n", testTime("120"));
  printf("the time is %d\n", testTime("0200"));
  printf("the time is %d\n", testTime("00200"));
  printf("the time is %d\n", testTime("2400"));
}
```

The function `int testTime(char *inputString);` will return `-1` and print an error message is the input time is not well formed; it will return the time (in hours) if it was properly formed.

Answer (score 0):

Well one first check can be as follows,

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
  if(start_time[i] > end_time[i]) {
    printf("\nIncorrect\n");
  }
}
```

In order to check the validity of the time entered the following check can be used,

```
int t,temp;
float ftemp;
printf("\nEnter Time : ");
scanf("%d",&t);
ftemp=temp=t;
ftemp=ftemp/100;
temp=temp/100;
if(temp > 23 || ftemp > temp) {
   printf("\n Invalid Time\n");
}
else {
   printf("\n Valid Time\n");
}
```

Suppose if the time is **2300**, 
then temp = 23 & ftemp = 23.00. So on Comparison `ftemp > temp` is **false** and the string is valid.
Suppose if the time is **2330**, 
then temp = 23 & ftemp = 23.30. So on Comparison `ftemp > temp` is **true** and the string is invalid.
Suppose if the time is **2500**, 
then temp = 25. So on Comparison `temp > 23` is **true** and the string is invalid.

Of course there might be even simpler validation tests possible.

Also in your program the following statements are incorrect,

```
return 0;             
main();
```

It should be,

```
main();
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since user specified valid time as a list, use the list.  Share routines as possible.

```
const char start_timeL[][5] = { "0800", "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300",
        "1400", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800", "1900", "2000", 0 };
const char end_timeL[][5] = { "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300", "1400",
        "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800", "1900", "2000", "2100", 0 };

bool valid_time(const char * timelist[], const char *testtime) {
  for (size_t i = 0; timelist[i]; i++) {
    if (strcmp(timelist[i], testtime) == 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

int Time_Get(const char *prompt, const char *valid_list[]) {
  for (;;) {
    int t;
    puts(prompt);
    char buf[10];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL)
      return -1;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &t) == 1) {
      if (t >= 0 && t <= 2400 && valid_time(valid_list, buf)) {
        return t;
      }
      puts("Invalid time %s", buf);
    }
  }

  int main() {
    int start_time = Time_Get("Enter start time: ", start_timeL);
    int end_time = Time_Get("Enter end   time: ", end_timeL);
    // do something with start_time & end_time
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code, though it still requires a fair bit of explanation:

```
/* Return "0800" as 8, "2300" as 23, etc. on success or -1 on error. */
int
valid_time(const char *timestr)
{
    long usertime;
    char *end;

    /* errno must be set to 0 before calling strtol */
    errno = 0;
    usertime = strtol(timestr, &end, 10);

    if (errno ||
        *end != '\0' ||
        end - timestr != 4 ||
        usertime % 100 != 0 ||
        usertime > 2300 ||
        usertime < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    return (int)(usertime / 100);
}
```

That does several things:

1. It converts as much of the string, ignoring leading spaces, to a numeric value, storing the remaining part of the string in `end`.
2. If there was an error in converting, `errno` is set.
3. `*end` will be `'\0'` if at the end of the time string, signifying the whole string was converted.
4. If the number of chars from the beginning of the time string entered to `end` is not 4, you got something like 900 or 25000.
5. If the converted time is not congruent modulo 100 to 0, the last two digits are not 0.
6. If the converted time is more than 2300 or less than 0, the time wasn't entered correctly.

Considering the fact that you included the leading 0 in 0800, I assumed it was meant to be included. Otherwise, you could change the condition slightly to check for `end - timestr < 3 || end - timestr > 4` instead of simply checking for a required length of 4.

Easier than handling the string stuff yourself in my opinion unless there is a need to optimise it in such a way as [@chux described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769335/time-validation-in-c/20769769#20769769): making use of commonly required string literals as much as possible.